# MacBook Pro running Vista often drops wireless connection when connected to Windows Home Server

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, windows-home-server

I've noticed when doing a backup or even just logging onto the WHS console, my MBP will lose it's wireless connection usually about once a session.  Any idea why?

Comment: How are the two machines connected to the router?

Comment: The WHS is wired, and the MBP is wireless.

Comment: @webjedi: so I guess then your macbook is loosing connection with your router, not with WHS? I think you will have to add more information for us to be able to supply a solution to your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately...there isn't a whole lot more to add.  I can sit with my laptop connected to say WoW for hours...no problem.  But when I connect to WHS...I'll be cruising along...and then all of a sudden the taskbar icon shows that I am not connected to a network.  Right click...reconnect all is good.  But this will also happen when I am doing a manual backup via the WHS...and this is no bueno.  Drivers are all updated...seems ducky, except for the random drops.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one rule of thumb: set the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) on your MBP and/or the router to **1490**, or maybe even little less.

The maximum is 1500 and it's usually the default on Mac and some routers. This may bring [some problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/73721/mtu-problems-request-timed-out) eventually. [Here](http://www.movie-forumz.org/showthread.php?p=404529) is a nice guide on how to optimize it. I hope that link doesn't break too soon. :P